# Install Certificate on a Different User's Current User Store

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, powershell-4.0

I am currently using the following code to add a certificate from the Local Machine store to the Current User Store, where $cert is the certificate.

```
$DestStoreScope = 'CurrentUser'
$DestStoreName = 'My'

$DestStore = New-Object  -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store  -ArgumentList $DestStoreName, $DestStoreScope
$DestStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
$DestStore.Add($cert)


$SourceStore.Close()
$DestStore.Close()
```

Is there a way that I could add this certificate to another users current store on this machine. It would be ran under the administrator account. Any help would be appreciated. If you need anything else, let me know!

Answer (score 4):

`CurrentUser`/`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is an abstraction in the registry. The actual user data is stored in the key `HKEY_USERS\<SID>`. Since `CurrentUser` always refers to the currently logged in user, and the API doesn't allow accessing the certificate store by a user's SID, your only option (AFAICS) is to run the script in the context of the user who you want to have the certificate installed.

Comment: And `HKEY_USERS\<SID>` is just a representation of `%USERPROFILE%\NTUSER.DAT`. If you have `HKEY_USERS` selected in RegEdit you can go to `File->Load Hive` and load a unloaded users registry by navigating to that file.